# Twitter OAuth 1 POST requests not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am creating an application for iOS and I am using this [OAuth library](https://github.com/Christian-Hansen/simple-oauth1). GET requests seem to work fine but as soon as I try to make POST requests I get the following error :

> [code 32] Could not authenticate you.

Now I am not quite sure what is happening, as POST requests are generated pretty similarly to the GET requests. Any ideas what is causing this error ?

Here is the code generating the request:

```
+ (NSURLRequest *)preparedRequestForPath:(NSString *)path
                              parameters:(NSDictionary *)queryParameters
                              HTTPmethod:(NSString *)HTTPmethod
                              oauthToken:(NSString *)oauth_token
                             oauthSecret:(NSString *)oauth_token_secret
{
    if (!HTTPmethod
        || !oauth_token) return nil;



    NSMutableDictionary *allParameters = [self standardOauthParameters];
    allParameters[@"oauth_token"] = oauth_token;
    if (queryParameters) [allParameters addEntriesFromDictionary:queryParameters];

    NSString *parametersString = CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(allParameters, NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    NSString *request_url = API_URL;
    if (path) request_url = [request_url stringByAppendingString:path];
    NSString *oauth_consumer_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET;
    NSString *baseString = [HTTPmethod stringByAppendingFormat:@"&%@&%@", request_url.utf8AndURLEncode, parametersString.utf8AndURLEncode];
    NSString *secretString = [oauth_consumer_secret.utf8AndURLEncode stringByAppendingFormat:@"&%@", oauth_token_secret.utf8AndURLEncode];
    NSString *oauth_signature = [self.class signClearText:baseString withSecret:secretString];
    allParameters[@"oauth_signature"] = oauth_signature;

    NSString *queryString;
    if (queryParameters) queryString = CHQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(queryParameters, NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    if (queryString) request_url = [request_url stringByAppendingFormat:@"?%@", queryString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:request_url]];
    request.HTTPMethod = HTTPmethod;

    NSMutableArray *parameterPairs = [NSMutableArray array];
    [allParameters removeObjectsForKeys:queryParameters.allKeys];
    for (NSString *name in allParameters) {
        NSString *aPair = [name stringByAppendingFormat:@"=\"%@\"", [allParameters[name] utf8AndURLEncode]];
        [parameterPairs addObject:aPair];
    }
    NSString *oAuthHeader = [@"OAuth " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [parameterPairs componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
    [request setValue:oAuthHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    if ([HTTPmethod isEqualToString:@"POST"]
        && queryParameters != nil) {
        NSData *body = [queryString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
    }

    return request;
}
```

## EDIT

The very last lines of the code where I set the HTTP body seem to cause the problem. When I remove the lines

```
 NSData *body = [queryString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 [request setHTTPBody:body];
```

everything works fine, except when the parameters are exceptionally bigger like sending a base64 encoded image, where it obviously fails... What could I possibly do to fix this ?

Comment: Are you using a synchronous or asynchronous NSURLConnection to retrieve this NSURLRequest?

Comment: @ModernCarpentry I am requesting asynchronously.

Comment: @the_critic what is the queryParameters here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following HTTP header fields:

```
[request setValue:@"api.twitter.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-HostCommonName"];
[request setValue:@"api.twitter.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[request setValue:@"https://api.twitter.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Target-URI"];
[request setValue:@"Keep-Alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well...

I don't know what is cause it exactly. [Can't send private message to non-follower.](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11860)

How about [API Console](https://dev.twitter.com/console)? It can be test Twitter APIs. maybe good to you.

First you test Direct Message API right way. and then compare results between API Console and your codes.

Comment: I am able to send messages, I just say that the culprit cannot be the permission because if I have access to direct messages then I surely would have to be able to make POST requests... But I am going to check out the console, that could potentially help me, I'll try it out and come back later.

Comment: Could you print 'queryString' and 'request_url' when return 'request'?     And I have Question! 'queryString' encoded UTF8 twice when method type 'POST' to setBody.

Comment: Why don't use [Twitter API Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries). Already exists Objective-C libraries. Have a any reason?

Comment: I am using a library and this code is from the library. If I log the body of the returned request `NSLog(@"body = %@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:preparedRequest.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` I get back an example value of "body = id=336959346300829698"

Comment: [401 error when trying to POST, no problems with GET](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1464) from twitter. Developer Twitter → Home → My application and then your Application's 'Settings' → 'Application Type' → checked 'Read, Write and Access direct messages' right?

Comment: Ok look at my question again I edited it and came to the conclusion that the HTTP body was the problem. However I have to send my query parameters with the HTTP body because if the parameters are to large, the request will not go through... So a little problem still remains